# My website serves properly on IP address but not on domain name

Tags: python, django, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I am using nginx, ubuntu 14, gunicorn, django 1.11, python 2.7.

I have put my domain in Allowed_HOSTS in the settings for django.

This is what I have under sites-available:

```
server {
        listen 8000;
        listen 80;
        server_name IP domain.com;

        location /static/ {
                root /home/username/website/src;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/website/website.sock;
        }
}
```

When I put in the IP address into a computer connected to the network, the site comes up just fine, but when I type in the domain I set up, it shows me this: [image: shows me an error that the site can't be reached].

Comment: You need to edit `/etc/hosts` to redirect the site to the specific IP address.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Like this? `IP       domain.com`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you have any good sources or tutorials about this? Because I can't find anything to help me learn how to connect a domain name to my IP.

Comment: I think this might be a start: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36009

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The /etc/hosts didn't seem to do anything. I'm probably missing something else as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have written up the process to get a wordpress site on the internet with a LAMP backend, for future reference that some might find useful.

Install LAMP stack:

- `sudo apt install lamp-server^ -y`

Install wordpress:

- `cd var/www/html/`
- `sudo wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz`
- `sudo chown www-data:www-data wordpress/`

Login to mysql root user:

- `sudo mysql -u root -p`
- select a password
- `create database wordpress;`
- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'server'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_password_here'`;
- `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
- `EXIT;`
- Navigate to `localhost/wordpress` in your browser and enter the information for database name, server name, password, leave `localhost` and `wp_` as is.

Now that you have wordpress running on your localhost environment, let's make it public.

Create a directory for site.

- `sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/mywebsite.com`
- `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/mywebsite.com`
- `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf/ /etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com.conf`

Open `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.com.conf` file to configure/modify your server settings (add options if they don't exist):

- `ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com`
- `ServerName www.mywebsite.com`
- `ServerAlias mywebsite.com`
- `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite.com`
- `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`
- `CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined`

Reload apache:

- `sudo a2ensite mywebsite.com.conf`
- `sudo systemctl restart apache2`
- `sudo service apache2 reload`

Add link between public IP (get from whatsmyip) and domain name (www.mywebsite.com)  in `/etc/hosts`:

- `123.456.789.123 www.mywebsite.com`

You can now go to `www.mywebsite.com/wordpress` to see your default wordpress page. 
`www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/wp-admin` will take you to the login page which you can use to login to your server.

References:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpMCBjTsZ60&t=56s
- https://code-maven.com/set-up-cgi-with-apache